# Fastest way to integrate a function that depends on a variable

Tags: python, optimization

I wish to evaluate the function y(x), which consists of an integral with the integrand depending on x. The integrand thus depends on two variables z and x. Here z is the variable that I wish to integrate over the range (0,1), and x is the variable that the function y(x) depends on.

The result should thus be an array `y` that is the integral of this integrand over `z` for each `x`.

My approach is the following

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

x = np.linspace(0,6,1000)

integrand = lambda z, x: z**x
y = lambda x: quad(integrand, 0, 1, args = (x))[0]
y = np.vectorize(y)(x)
```

This works, but it also takes some time if I want to do more complicated integrals multiple times. This makes me wonder if there is a way to improve the computation time for this procedure. Please ignore the fact that here the integral can be solved analytically. This is just an illustrative example.

Comment: [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) *The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop*. There will be no benefits using `vectorize`. To optimize a particular function we need a concrete example. There is no general optimization pattern.

Comment: I have included the real function that I use, but I am not entirely sure how that would make a difference.

Comment: Your code is not valid and you have undefined variables. To my surprise, your first example runs 1.5x faster with `np.vectorize(y)` than a list comprehension and is more convenient to use.